# Apache LocationMatch regex ignores duplicate slashes

Tags: regex, apache, weblogic, slash, locationmatch

I'm having a strange behaviour with Apache's LocationMatch directive when there are extra slashes at the beginning of the URL. According to the Apache docs if I'm reading it right this should work:

```
    <LocationMatch ^/appcontext/(a|b)>

            SetHandler weblogic-handler
            WebLogicCluster apphost01:xxxx,apphost02:xxxx
            WLProxySSL ON

    </LocationMatch>
```

However if I type the following URL it is also being forwarded to the backend hosts:

https:// <hostname:port> ////////appcontext/a/

In the Apache docs it clearly states that it should apply the directive only for /appcontext/a/, unless I'm missing something with the regex or there is some issue with the mod_wl plug-in

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html

"For example, <LocationMatch ^/abc> would match the request URL /abc but not the request URL //abc"

Does anyone have any suggestion to achieve this?

Comment: `^/appcontext/(a|b)` will also match `///appcontext/a/` also (any # of of `/` before `appcontext`) since those are considered redundant slashes. What problem is it causing?

Comment: I could be wrong, but that doesn't even seem like a valid URI. The part after `//`, being `////////appcontext/a/`, is not a valid authority component nor a valid path (since it begins with `//` and does not follow an authority). http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3

Comment: We have a cookie with a Location directive for /appcontext/a and the browser doesn't consider the slashes redundant (it doesn't send the cookie for ///appcontext/a/ only for /appcontext/a/)

Comment: Then it is better to redirect `////app` to `/app` using a rewrite rule.

Comment: For it to have any effect on the client browser you mean a Redirect rule correct? AFAIK a rewrite rule would still expose the incorrect URL to the browser and the cookie would not work. But if the regex doesn't work for LocationMatch, would it work for a RedirectMatch?

Comment: Yes I meant an external redirect rule in client browser.

Comment: @RyanM, sorry, the hostname:port & LocationMatch were misinterpreted as HTML tags, fixed it

Comment: @anubhava tried the RedirectMatch but it seems to suffer from the same issue:

RedirectMatch 302 ^//+ /appcontext/a/

Tried the same rule but with ^/a+ and it worked (/aaaa redirected correctly to /appcontext/a/), seems Apache is somehow collapsing the extra forward slashes before it processes the regex rules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes Apache does collapse extra slashes in rewrite rule. You can use `THE_REQUEST` variable to match and remove extra slashes. Place this in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)//+(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2 [R=302,L,NE]
```

Comment: Unfortunately we are not using .htaccess since this is a Virtual path, however I have found a similar answer in a different post that also works inside the VirtualHost in the .conf file:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781237/how-can-i-301-redirect-multiple-leading-slashes-file-txt-to-just-file-txt

I could not test your version but I will mark the answer as accepted, thank you for your time.

Comment: Thanks for accepting it. Yes indeed that answer will work in Virtual path.